# Como rebobinar o ponteiro de arquivo corretamente em Java?

Tags: java, c

Na realidade o problema é bem complexo, mas eu vou tentar dar uma noção que acho que vai ser compreensível.

Eu tenho um método numa aplicação que inicializa objetos para E/S em conformidade com um "contexto global" (na realidade isso é um conceito da minha aplicação). Esse método tem o papel de deixarem prontos objetos para operações de E/S.

```
public void setupSpaceIO() throws IOException {
    if(globalContext.isThereSpaceLoaded()) {
        accountReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(globalContext.getSpace().getAccountsPath()),
                BANC_GEN_STD_CHARSET);
        accountWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(globalContext.getSpace().getAccountsPath()),
                BANC_GEN_STD_CHARSET, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        userReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(globalContext.getSpace().getUsersPath()),
                BANC_GEN_STD_CHARSET);
        userWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(globalContext.getSpace().getUsersPath()),
                BANC_GEN_STD_CHARSET, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no space loaded!");
    }

    accountReader.mark(1);
    userReader.mark(1);
}
```

Os objetos escritores funcionam normalmente. Mas os leitores é que são o problema. Suponha-se que eles estejam lendo um arquivo com este conteúdo:

```
Linha 1
Linha 2
Linha 3
```

Se eu chamar um método como "readLine()" ele lerá a primeira linha normalmente. Mas a partir daí não será mais possível ler a primeira linha denovo se eu assim desejar. Sim, no método setupSpaceIO() são chamados os métodos mark() que a princípio que estou com dificuldade de entender e eu os chamei com o objetivo de deixar um "rebobinador" pronto para ser chamado com o método reset(). O problema é que chamando o método eu só consigo IOExceptions.

E não vi nenhuma classe do java.io que tivesse um método parecido com o rewind() do C.

Como eu rebobino o ponteiro de leitura do arquivo para o início dele em Java?

Answer (score 4):

## BufferedReader

Você pode rebobinar um BufferedReader através dos métodos `mark(int readAheadLimit)` e `reset()`. Funciona assim, em determinado ponto da sua leitura você marca aquela posição, e quando você chamar o reset a stream volta para a posição marcada.

O inconveniente é o parâmetro do método mark() que espera que você informe a quantidade máxima de caracteres que você pode ler antes de rebobinar, ou seja, se você tem um arquivo de 2.000 caracteres você precisa fazer:

```
file.mark(2000);
//código aqui para ler todas as linhas
file.reset();
```

Você pode indicar um tamanho maior do que a quantidade de caracteres do seu arquivo, entretanto se seu arquivo for muito grande você pode ter impactos significativos de desempenho.

Ao calcular o tamanho do buffer que o mark() deverá criar lembre-se que cada linha pulada conta como dois caracteres.

Use essa possibilidade caso você saiba o tamanho do seu arquivo, mesmo que aproximadamente, e caso ele não seja muito grande.

Se você passar como argumento um tamanho menor que o buffer lerá você receberá um IOException.

Referência: [BufferedReader - Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

## RandomAccessFile

Uma possibilidade versátil é usar a classe RandomAccessFile.

Ele possui o método `seek(long pos)` que permite você apontar para qualquer parte do seu arquivo. Apenas preste atenção pois ele espera como argumento um long indicando a posição no texto, e não a posição da linha.

Exemplo:

**teste.txt**

> linha 1
> linha 2
> linha 3

**Random.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("teste.txt", "r");
        String linha;
        while((linha = file.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(linha);
        }
        file.seek(9); //vai para a posição 9 no teste.txt, que é o início da 2ª linha
        while((linha = file.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(linha);
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Saída:

> linha 1
> linha 2
> linha 3
> linha 2
> linha 3

`linha 1` possui 7 caracteres, e a quebra de linha conta como 2, por isso que `file.seek(9);` apontou para o primeiro caractere da segunda linha. Se quiser voltar para a primeira posição do seu arquivo faça `file.seek(0);` que seria equivalente ao `rewind()` em C.

Referência: [RandomAccessFile - Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

## Conclusão

No JDK, costuma-se ter muitas classes sendo que cada uma é especialista para um determinado propósito. Nos dois exemplo acima não é diferente, você tem duas ferramentas e tem que saber a hora certa de escolher cada uma delas.

Se você precisa de velocidade e vai ler um arquivo sequencialmente, ou seja, não precisará trocar o ponteiro de posição, o BufferedReader é a escolha certa, seu uso é geralmente em arquivos muitos grandes e você quer lê-lo inteiro. Fazendo essa escolha você enfrentará o efeito colateral que é a falta de navagabilidade no seu arquivo. O método mark() dentro dessa classe me parece muito difícil de ser usado com robustez, já que seu uso é bem limitado, EU particularmente não me sentiria a vontade de usá-lo pois acho que não compensa o risco de gerar um exceção em tempo de execução.

Se a sua necessidade é a navegabilidade a sua melhor escolha será a classe RandomAccessFile, que possui o método seek(), entretanto ela não cria um buffer do arquivo, logo, você terá que abrir mão da velocidade na execução das operações.

Sobre seu comentário:

> Milhares de classes só pra I/O e uma curva de aprendizado desnecessária pra aprendar a usá-las.

Ao desenvolvermos sistemas pequenos, a infinidade de classes que o Java oferece parece mais como um martírio do que uma salvação, já que em uma aplicação de apenas alguns pacotes com no máximo uma dúzia classes e um banco de dados na casa dos MB, os termos "velocidade" e "desempenho" praticamente não precisam ser levados em consideração, já que a diferença é quase que irrisória. Entretanto em um sistema que possui centenas de pacotes e classes e que enfrenta constantemente um tráfego de dados extremamente intenso, as milhares de classes do Java proporcionam uma versatilidade que resultarão em um sistema otimizado.

Se a sua aplicação é pequena, foque naquilo que te dá mais agilidade na hora do desenvolvimento, já que o desempenho em tempo de execução será praticamente o mesmo. Eu iria de RandomAccessFile.

Comment: Entendi. Então quer dizer que a medida que o arquivo cresce eu preciso recaucular o tamanho dele para chamar o mark() denovo? Não é ruim, mas porque Java precisa ser tão "frescurento"? Milhares de classes só pra I/O e uma curva de aprendizado desnecessária pra aprendar a usá-las.

Comment: @Sid é vdd, a curva de aprendizado do Java é algo doloroso, entretanto tente não se apegar muito aos detalhes caso sua aplicação não pede algo extremamente otimizado, foque naquilo que te dá agilidade na hora do desenvolvimento. PS: editei a resposta a partir de onde tá escrito **conclusão**