# Leitura de arquivos de maneira inversa

Tags: java

Meu objetivo é ler um arquivo (linha por linha), porém, iniciando pelo final do arquivo (ultima linha) até o início (primeira linha).

Alguém poderia dar uma possível ideia de realizar esse procedimento?

Estava usando `RandomAcessFile` com o intuito de utilizar o `seek` para o final do arquivo e ir voltando, porém não deu muito certo.

Comment: Até é possível, mas acho que vai ficar uma gambiarra enorme. Você tem a necessidade de fazer desse jeito? Pois o ideal seria você ler o arquivo inteiro e depois ir pegando as linhas de trás para frente. Dá uma olhada nesse tópico: [Como rebobinar o ponteiro de arquivo corretamente em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21387/3117)

Comment: Se forem arquivos muito grandes, e linhas de tamanho variáveis, eu sugeriria uma "lida" pra frente para indexar as linhas e posição, e usar o seek com o índice pronto na volta. Tem casos legítimos pra isso, em situações em que o arquivo não caberia todo na memória sem penalidade de performance e o processamento linha a linha realmente tenha que ser inverso. Mas há uma grande probabilidade de não ser o seu caso específico. Outra saída para situação similar, é ler o arquivo em blocos fixos, de por exemplo 8K em 8K, do fim pro começo, e você escanear as quebras das linhas em cada bloco.

Answer (score 1):

[`Files#readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) te retorna uma lista com todas as linhas do arquivo. Então pode usar [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) para inverter a ordem dessa lista:

```
List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("foo/bar.txt"));
Collections.reverse(linhas);
```

Pode usar [`List#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) para obter cada linha do arquivo posteriormente: `linhas.get(0);` (que devolveria a primeira linha) retornará a última, e assim por diante...

#### [Funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@reebr/Leitura-de-Arquivos-de-Maneira-Inversa)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está a implementação:

```
 /**
 * Input stream utilizado para ler um arquivo em ordem reversa
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664705/how-to-read-file-from-end-to-start
 * -in-reverse-order-in-java
 *
 *
 */
class ReverseLineInputStream extends InputStream {

    RandomAccessFile in;

    long currentLineStart = -1;
    long currentLineEnd = -1;
    long currentPos = -1;
    long lastPosInFile = -1;

    public ReverseLineInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        in = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        currentLineStart = file.length();
        currentLineEnd = file.length();
        lastPosInFile = file.length() - 1;
        currentPos = currentLineEnd;
    }

    public void findPrevLine() throws IOException {

        currentLineEnd = currentLineStart;

        // There are no more lines, since we are at the beginning of the file
        // and no lines.
        if (currentLineEnd == 0) {
            currentLineEnd = -1;
            currentLineStart = -1;
            currentPos = -1;
            return;
        }

        long filePointer = currentLineStart - 1;

        while (true) {
            filePointer--;

            // we are at start of file so this is the first line in the file.
            if (filePointer < 0) {
                break;
            }

            in.seek(filePointer);
            int readByte = in.readByte();

            // We ignore last LF in file. search back to find the previous LF.
            if (readByte == 0xA && filePointer != lastPosInFile) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // we want to start at pointer +1 so we are after the LF we found or at
        // 0 the start of the file.
        currentLineStart = filePointer + 1;
        currentPos = currentLineStart;
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {

        if (currentPos < currentLineEnd) {
            in.seek(currentPos++);
            int readByte = in.readByte();
            return readByte;

        } else if (currentPos < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            findPrevLine();
            return read();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Usando ele:

```
ReverseLineInputStream reverseLineInputStream = new RverseLineInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(reverseLineInputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Comment: Coloque a referência: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11665098/1964435 Se possível também traduzir as explicações nos comentários para português seria uma boa.